# WPF IDataErrorInfo different control styles for HasError and required fields

Tags: wpf, validation, idataerrorinfo

I'm using IDataErrorInfo in my entity classes to do validation of entity objects. I have this working and displaying any validation issues in the visual style I want for each control using the Validation.ErrorTemplate.

For example a TextBox control I'm using the Validation.ErrorTemplate to adorn the TextBox with a red border and an exclamation point icon with a Tooltip describing the validation error.

Now I'd like to soften up the look of the UI a bit.  When a user opens a data entry form, I want to change the background color of required fields to Light Blue. I don't want to use the Validation.ErrorTemplate with a jarring red border and exclamation point until they at least enter some data in the TextBox that doesn't validate.

I want to keep the validation and required field logic in the entity class, and keep the UI declarative.  Is there a pattern I can use or another class I need to be looking at for this functionality?  I was playing with using a DataTrigger in the TextBox style on Validation.HasError and a MultiValueConveter to check if I have a validation error and the value of the control is null or empty string, but not having a lot of luck and it seems there should be an easier way.

For example, my entity class that implements IDataErrorInfo returns a validation error e.g. "Email Address is required" if the Email property was null or empty, and another validation error e.g. "Email Address does not appear to be formatted correctly" when the Email property is set to a string that doesn't validate to be a valid email address.  If there the Email property is set to null or empty, I want to just set the Background to LightBlue.  If there is a string in the Email property, but it is not a valid email address, I want to show the Validation.ErrorTemplate.

EDIT

```
public class MyEntity : IDataErrorInfo
{
    private static readonly IList<PropertyInfo> BindableProperties;

    static MyEntity()
    {
        BindableProperties = typeof(MyEntity).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite).ToList();
    }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public Boolean IsValid()
    {
        return BindableProperties.All(p => this[p.Name] == null);
    }

    #region // IDataErrorInfo Members

    public string this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            string message = null;

            switch (name)
            {
                ...

                case "Email":

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(Email);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            message = "Email does not appear to be a valid email address.";
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message = "Email is required";
                    }

                    break;

                ...
            }

            return message;
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    #endregion // IDataErrorInfo Members
}
```

Controls XAML

```
<TextBox Name="EmailTextBox" Text="{Binding MyEntity.Email, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>

<Button x:Name="SaveButton" Command="Save" Content="Save">
    <Button.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="Save" Executed="Save_Executed" CanExecute="Save_CanExecute"/>
    </Button.CommandBindings>
</Button>
```

Code Behind

```
private void Save_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = MyEntity.IsValid();
}
```

Comment: why it is Validating when you open the DataEntry form . I think then you should be setting just new instance of the Entity

Comment: I am creating a new instance of the entity. I have ValidatesOnDataErrors=True set in the binding, so as soon as the binding source is updated, the Validation.ErrorTemplate is shown

Comment: Thats what am trying to say that Binding source will update only when you will enter values in textbox . or are you putting some values through code

Comment: I have a button on the form that has a Command binding and the CanExecute is checking each property on the entity object to see if it is valid through the IDataErrorInfo indexer implementation. So I'm assuming it knows a blank email is invalid right off the bat.

Comment: Can you please show the code of this entity?

Comment: Some code is posted. So the goal is when the user opens the form, the save button is disabled until MyEntity validates. Any field that does not have a value and has a validation error have a LightBlue background and any fields with a value and validation error would have a Red border.

Comment: I developed a [validation decorator](http://codedreams.blogspot.com/2010/04/wpf-validation-feedback-with.html) that displays validation feedback for its child control.  It includes support for separate "required field" UI hints.  Feel free to take a look and adapt it as necessary.

Comment: @MikeStrobel it appears to me your code sets if a field is required in the UI, I want to keep that defined in the entity

Comment: @Dude0001 Correct.  That seemed the most straightforward option for a decorator control, which doesn't know anything about the type of control it wraps or which of its properties is bound.  Automatically determining whether to show the required field indicator is tricky.  If you know which property is bound on the child control, you can analyze the binding to determine which property it binds to, and then look for a `[Required]` annotation, but that seems clunky.  I don't know of an elegant or standard way to communicate required fields separately from other validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your Entity.Here Employee is an Entity.

```
public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged,IDataErrorInfo
{
    private static readonly IList<PropertyInfo> BindableProperties;

    static Employee()
    {
        BindableProperties = typeof(Employee).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite).ToList();
    }

    string email;

    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set {
            email = value; 
            Validate(true,"Email");
            Notify("Email");
        }
    }

    public Boolean IsValid()
    {
        return BindableProperties.All(p => Validate(false,p.Name));
    }

    bool Validate(bool addErrors, string propName)
    {
        string message = string.Empty;

        switch (propName)
        {
            case "Email":
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(Email);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        message = "Email does not appear to be a valid email address.";
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    message = "Email is required";
                }
                break;
        }

        if (addErrors)
            AddOrRemoveError(propName, message);

        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(message);
    }

    void AddError(string propertyName, string error)
    {
        if (!errors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            errors.Add(propertyName, error);
    }

    void RemoveError(string propertyName)
    {
        if (errors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            errors.Remove(propertyName);
    }

    void AddOrRemoveError(string propName,string message)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            AddError(propName, message);
        else
            RemoveError(message);
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void Notify(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get { if(errors.ContainsKey(columnName)) return errors[columnName]; else return null;}
    }
}
```

Comment: I do like using the dictionary of invalid fields, but this does nothing to handle blank required fields different than fields with data entry errors.